# CSS Selector when radio button is checked

Tags: html, css

I am using images as a radio buttons:

```html
<label class="radio-inline thumbs"><input type="radio" id="type_nee" name="type" value="nee" onkeyup="validate()" onclick="validate()"> <img src="assets/images/basis.png"  height="75"> </label>
<label class="radio-inline thumbs"><input type="radio" id="type_ja" name="type" value="ja" onkeyup="validate()" onclick="validate()"> <img src="assets/images/bottom.png" height="75"> </label>
```

I am hiding the radio button with:

```css
   input[type=radio]:not(old){
      width   : 28px;
      margin  : 0;
      padding : 0;
      opacity : 0;
    }
```

The image is made transparent with:

```
.thumbs{opacity:0.5;}
```

I would like to remove the opacity filter when the image (= radio button) is clicked.
Which CSS selector to use?
I have tried

```
.thumbs:active{opacity:1;}
```

and

```
.thumbs:checked{opacity:1;}
```

With no result. Any suggestions how to remove the opacity filter when image (= radio button) is checked?

Comment: It’s `:checked`, but you have to use it on the right element - it is _not_ the label that gets checked ... And you can not select upwards in the DOM, so you can not change the styling of the label based on the checkbox state. What you can do, is style the image, because that is a following sibling of the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Example, just change your HTML and CSS

```css
input[type=radio]:not(old){
   width   : 28px;
   margin  : 0;
   padding : 0;
   opacity : 0;
}

.thumbs{opacity:0.5;}

.testchecked:checked + label > img {opacity:1;}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="type_nee" class="testchecked" name="type" value="nee">
<label for="type_nee" class="radio-inline">
  <img class="thumbs" src="assets/images/basis.png"  height="75">
</label>

<input type="radio" id="type_ja" class="testchecked" name="type" value="ja">
<label for="type_ja" class="radio-inline">
  <img class="thumbs" src="assets/images/bottom.png" height="75"></label>
```

Comment: Nice!! Thank you for this eye opener.